# Which is the function that initializes the content of the "$scripts" variable used in html.tlp.php?

Tags: 7, theming

The template file [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php/7) has access to the `$scripts` variable, which is not initialized in [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7). I have also looked at [template_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7), and [template_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_process/7), but neither of those functions initialize `$scripts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$scripts` variable is initialized in [`template_process_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7), which uses the following code.

```php
$variables['css'] = drupal_add_css();
$variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
```

Comment: They forgot to add a link to that function, in the documentation for [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php/7). Thank you.

Comment: feel free to post a patch :p